# hydroTSM rainfall interpolation

Tags: r, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate using IDWrainfall data from 8 raingauge stations in R-studio using hydroTSM package . Everything went well until the last point where I get the error below. I cant decode what it means. Anybody can help?

#

```
xL.idw <- hydrokrige(x.ts= RAINFALLDATA, x.gis=EbroPPgischanged,
+                     X="EAST_ED50", Y="NORTH_ED50", sname="ID",
+                     bname="CHE_BASIN",
+                     type= "block",
+                     subcatchments= lowaat_catchments,
+                     cell.size= 3000,
+                     ColorRamp= "Precipitation")
[ Subb IDs: ]
0  1  
[Subcatchments found: 2 ]
['predictors' was not provided. Computing the grid...]

[ Date: 1/1/1960 ]
[Starting grid interpolations...]
[inverse distance weighted interpolation]
[Starting block interpolations...]
E*rror in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘overlay’ for signature ‘"SpatialPixelsDataFrame", "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"’
############################*
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the error caused by the change in "sp" package. we have to wait for the new update from hydroTSM.

More detail see here: https://www.rforge.net/hydroTSM/index.html

Comment: Actually they updated the hydroTSM package, if you update it through github, it will run smoothly now.